# Java - Why the following code print out "BAC", instead of "ABC"?

Tags: java, tostring

Please help me understand this code. I am new to java.

```
// C.java
class C { 
  public static void main(String arg[]) { 
    System.out.println("A"+new C()); 
  } 
  public String toString() { 
    System.out.print("B"); 
    return "C"; 
  } 
}
// output:
// BAC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need understand 2 concepts here: **Java left-to-right evaluation rule** and **side effect**.

```
"A"+new C()
```

following the same rule. It gets "A" first, which is a String literal, put it somewhere. Then it evaluate

```
new C()
```

it construct a `C Object` first, then invoke `toString()` method of C Object, and gets the value of C object, which is "`C`", then concatenates "`A`" and "`C`" together, and println "`AC`".

Inside the `toString()` method of C Object, there is a `System.out.print("B");`
which is invoked when Java evaluate the above expression. It is printed out before the evaluation completed.
That is why "`B`" is printed first

Answer (score 9):

The evaluation goes something like:

```
Call println("A" + new C())
Since new C() hasn't been computed yet, we need to compute it, so...
Compute new C().toString()
    Print "B"
Print line with "A" + "C"
```

As you can see, the order of the print statements is "B", "A", "C"

Answer (score 2):

Because the `new C()` is converted to a string, and *then* passed to `println()`. Basically, here's what happens:

```
1. Concatenate "A" with new C():
  a. Call String.valueOf(new C()):
    i. print "B"
    ii. return "C"
  b. Concatenate "A" and "C"
2. Pass "AC" to println
3. Print "AC"
```

AFAIK (I'm not 100% sure) string concatenation uses [`String#valueOf(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) rather than directly calling `Object#toString()`. That's why `"foo" + null` is `"foonull"` rather than `[throw a NullPointerException]`.